# Semelhança de dados com vários valores pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho a seguinte lista de pandas

[image: list]

O objetivo do programa é obter o grau de similaridade de acordo com os dados inseridos. neste caso é um programa para consultar casas, e eu já fiz para consultar casas com os mesmos dados que o utilizador indica, mas no caso de o utilizador indicar não existir na base de dados o objetivo é aparecer casas semelhantes ...

para consultar as casas com as mesmas variaveis usei este código

```
lista = ListaCompleta[ListaCompleta.Concelho.isin(concelhos) & (ListaCompleta['Tipo Imovel'] == tipo_imv) & 
                                      (ListaCompleta['Estado'] == estad) & (ListaCompleta['Quartos'] == quar) & 
                                      ListaCompleta.Preco.notnull()]
```

mas se o que o utilizador inserir não existir na base de dados, quero crie uma nova coluna em que insira um valor entre 0 e 1 em que 1 seja exatamente o mesmo e 0 não seja o mesmo (para cada linha)

Para calcular a semelhança de cada coluna de cada linha, pensei em usar esse código (não sei se é o melhor)

(as variáveis "quart", "casa_banh", "area", "garag", "ano" são inseridas pelo usuário)

```
similar_quartos = (quart-ListaCompleta['Quartos'])/5
similar_casa_banho = (casa_banh-ListaCompleta['Casa Banho'])/3
similar_area = (area-ListaCompleta['Area'])/200
similar_garagem = (garag-ListaCompleta['Garagem'])/3
similar_ano = (ano-ListaCompleta['Ano'])/30
```

mas depois preciso de juntar á lista, eu tentei este código, mas não está a dar

```
lista['similiariedade'] = lista[(similar_quartos+similar_casa_banho+similar_area+similar_garagem+similar_ano)/5]
```

e criar uma coluna com um valor de 0 a 1 em cada linha da lista, para saber qual
casa é mais semelhante à que o utilizador inseriu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma abordagem é calcular a distância de um novo dado e os dados do Data Frame, calculando a dissimilaridade. Para isso, sugiro utilizar a **[Distância de Gower](https://towardsdatascience.com/clustering-on-mixed-type-data-8bbd0a2569c3)**. Ela funciona da seguinte forma:

### Distância de Gower

Dado um novo dado e um dado do df, primeiro calculamos a distância entre cada atributo (coluna do df), com `0` caso seja igual (menor distância possível) e `1` caso a distância seja máxima. Depois, calculamos a média das distâncias de todos os atributos.

Para **dados categóricos**, como as suas colunas `Concelho`, `Estado` e `Mobilada`, a distância é `0` caso seja a mesma categoria e `1` caso seja de categoria diferente. Exemplo:

```
   Concelho  Estado  Mobilada
0   Caminha  Usado   nao
1   Caminha  Usado   sim
```

A distância entre estas linhas é `[0, 0, 1]`, ou seja, `0.33` na média, pois `Concelho` e `Estado` são iguais, mas `Mobilada` é diferente.

Para **dados numéricos**, sejam eles contínuos ou ordinais, calculamos a distância pela fórmula `distancia = |Xi - Xj|/distancia_maxima_observada`, onde `i` é uma linha e `j` é outra linha. Exemplo:

```
     Ano   Area    Preco
0   1995     80    75000
1   1937    132   105000
2   2007    252   775000
3   2009    225   697000
4   1995    234   385000
```

Temos que a maior distância observada na coluna `Ano` é `2009 - 1937 = 72`, da coluna `Area` é `252 - 80 = 172` e da coluna `Preco` é `775000 - 75000 = 700000`. Assim, calculando a distância de cada coluna para as linhas 0 e 1, e temos: `[|1995-1937|/72, |80-132|/172, |75000-105000|/700000]`, e na média temos `0.38`.

### Aplicando com Python

Dada esta função que faz as contas descritas acima:

```
def gower_distance(new_data, df):
    distances = []
    for column in df.columns: #Para cada coluna do df
        if (df[column].dtype == np.object): # Se o tipo da coluna for np.object, é um dado categórigo
            columns_distance = np.where(df[column] == new_data[column].values[0], 0, 1)
        else: # Se não for um dado categórico, é numérico
            max_range_observed = df[column].values.max()-df[column].values.min()
            columns_distance = ((df[column] - new_data[column].values[0]).abs()/(max_range_observed)).fillna(0).values

        distances.append(columns_distance)

    return np.array(distances).mean(axis=0)
```

Seja um novo dado como:

```
new_data = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Tipo Imovel':['Moradia'],
    'Estado':['Usado'],
    'Concelho':['Caminha'],
    'Quartos':[4],
    'Casa Banho':[1],
    'Mobilada':['sim'],
    'Area':[225],
    'Garagem':[1.0],
    'Ano':[2009],
    'Preco':[697000]})
```

Podemos adicionar a coluna com a distância calculada assim:

`df['gower_dist'] = gower_distance(new_data, df[df.columns.difference(['gower_dist'])])`

Porém, esta é uma media de dissimilaridade. Para calcularmos a similaridade, basta fazer:
 `df['similaridade'] = 1 - df['gower_dist']`

Assim, a coluna `similaridade` terá `1` caso o novo dado seja igual e terá `0` se for exatamente o oposto.

```
       Ano  Area  Casa Banho  Concelho  Estado  Garagem  Mobilada   Preco  Quartos  Tipo Imovel  gower_dist  similaridade
1   1937.0   132          1    Caminha   Usado      1.0      sim   105000       2    Moradia       0.288641   0.711359
2   2007.0   252          1    Caminha   Usado      1.0      nao   775000       3    Moradia       0.154618   0.845382
3   2009.0   225          1    Caminha   Usado      1.0      sim   697000       4    Moradia       0.000000   1.000000
4   1995.0   234          3    Caminha   Usado      1.0      sim   385000       5    Moradia       0.194248   0.805752
```

Uma ressalva é que, para dados com `NaN`, não é possível calcular a distância de gower pelo código acima. Sugiro tratá-los antes ou usar um `.dropna()`.

Comment: está-me a dar o seguinte erro: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')

Comment: Este erro ocorre quando tenta fazer operações (+ ou -) com inteiros e string, como `pd.Series(['abc', 'def']) - pd.Series([1, 2])`. Pode me dar mais informações de quando o erro ocorre?

Comment: já consegui resolver, por alguma razão no ciclo for estava a colocar a variavel column como tipo string, logo dava erro, e também usei o pd.to_numeric() para colocar tudo numérico no else para não dar merda